# Generalized Jensen's inequality for positively homogeneous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

The function $f:V \to \hat{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be positively homogeneous iff $f(\alpha v) = \alpha f(v)$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$. Here $V$ is a real vector space and $\hat{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Convex function is positively homogeneous iff its epigraph is a convex cone. So, to be brief I will call such function a **conic function** (This is note a standard nomenclature) . If $f$ is conic (and proper, so $f(x) \neq -\infty$) then it is subadditive. Moreover, $f\left(\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_i v_i\right) \le \sum^n_{i=1} \lambda_i f(v_i)$ for any $v \in V^n,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++}$.

This made me wander whether it is possible to extend this to integration in style of Jensen's inequality for arbitrary positive measure $\mu$:
$$
(1)\quad f\left(\int_\Omega x(\omega) \; d\mu \right) \le \int_\Omega f(x(\omega)) \; d\mu,
$$

where $x : \Omega \to V$ is a function with a vector integral over $\mu$. Inequality (1) actually holds in case $V = \mathbb{R}^n$. See article [A Convexity inequality by Paolo Roselli and Michel Willem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268313622_A_Convexity_Inequality)
. Overall, I think I also got an idea how to prove (1) in finite-dimensional case.

So, the natural question is whether this result can be extended to Bochner or Pettis integral for Banach or general topological vector spaces? Clearly (1) holds when $\mu$ has density $\rho$ with respect to some probability measure $\pi$:

$$
\begin{multline}
f\left(\int_\Omega x(\omega) \; d\mu \right)  =
f\left(\int_\Omega x(\omega)\rho(\omega) \; d\pi \right)\le 
\int_\Omega f\Big(x(\omega)\rho(\omega)\Big) \;d\pi = \\ =
\int_\Omega f(x(\omega))\rho(\omega) \; d\pi  = \int_\Omega f(x(\omega))d\mu.
\end{multline}
$$

But in this case $\mu$ must be at most $\sigma$-finite. And in case of $\sigma$-finite $\mu$ there is other ways to prove (1). So, can (1) fail in case of $V$ being an infinite dimensional topological vector space and $\mu$ not being $\sigma$-finite? We may assume that $xd\mu$ is a vector measure of bounded variation, so do we need $V$ to have Radon-Nikodym property? Or in general may there be some additional conditions on $V$? Have you seen any results on this topic?

*discussion:*

Jochen Wengenroth suggests using linear approximation of conic function $f$. Denote by $\mathcal{L}(f) = \{ g : g\;\text{is linear and}\; g \le f  \}$. Then one can write:

$$
\begin{multline}
f\left( \int_\Omega x(\omega) \; d\mu\right) = \sup_{g \in \mathcal{L}(f)} g\left( \int_\Omega x(\omega) \; d\mu\right)=_{(2)}
\sup_{g \in \mathcal{L}(f)}  \int_\Omega g\big(x(\omega)\big) \; d\mu \le_{(3)} \\ \le_{(3)} \int_\Omega \sup_{g \in \mathcal{L}(f)} g\big( x(\omega) \big) \; d\mu = \int_\Omega f\big( x(\omega) \big) \; d\mu
\end{multline}
$$

Here functions $g$ always exist and (3) is a simple integral majorization which should always work. On the other hand (2) may fail is $g$ is not a closed linear functional. Note, that if we extend such unbounded non-closed linear functional $h$  by $+\infty$, so $f(x) = h(x)$ for $x \in D(h)$ and $f(x) = +\infty$ otherwise. This would be an example of nowhere continuous conic function, where step (2) may fail. However, if $f$ is lower semicontinuous or equivalently has closed convex cone as its epigraph, there always exists a continuous affine minorant. So if I understood everything correctly, I can always get continuous linear functionals to compute (2). So (1) will always hold if $V$ is a Banach space and $f$ is closed.

*Roselli, Paolo; Willem, Michel*, [**A convexity inequality.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2695768), Am. Math. Mon. 109, No. 1, 64-70 (2002). [ZBL1037.26019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1037.26019).

Comment: Subadditive und positively homogenous function are called *sublinear* and feature in the Hahn-Banach theorem. Did you try to choose a linear $g\le f$ with $f(I)=g(I)$ where $I$ is the integral?

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice. The Hahn-Banach theorem as I know it uses sublinear functionals $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$ which are finite everywhere. The difference here is that I allow conic functions to have value $+\infty$. So, this may produce some discontinuities and I see these discontinuities as the main obstacle for this inequality to hold.  See a discussion  part I wrote. Nevertheless, I think you suggested an interesting track for my thoughts.